# ssh-2 rsa body format?

Tags: ssh, rsa

Is there any documentation on what the bignums in the body are?

Like here is an example pubkey.

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBMgigwcBaB3sqogC/yVPANQJKjMwOvrdOKhBIVlI2eOIq6FEyzNI8cbRDbHo5muipun922bLoV+p/dPZ2/8wJ+zugLM8eCdsr+VbYZ3T5wb7bjd2swePOWtffnsXnHiP8aWyRj64vd/mRPR1gYErg8vb7vM5c4B2ANKHs/rP65Bw== rsa-key-20100514

It contains 3 bignums with the sizes 7, 1, 128. Now I am assuming the 128 is the key while the 7 is the shared. But what about the other one? Also the privkey contains a lot more bignums which I have no idea what they are.

Edit:

So apparently what I am looking for is the format of the private key blob. I have searched and all I have found are references to the name and not the actual format.

Answer (score 1):

The number with size 1 is the "version". What you observe is the encoding of a structure which contains the key elements. The structure follows [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) conventions and encoding rules. In the case of RSA, the contents of the public and private keys are specified by [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) (see annex C for the ASN.1 specification, and section 3 for the human readable text).

Comment: Where in the PKCS does it say what the different bignums are?

Comment: In annex C for the ASN.1 specification, in section 3 for the human readable text.

Comment: I meant in the above structure. Like how am I supposed to know which ones in the ssh private key are which?